# Как добавить https в условие?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Из-за двойного условия иногда происходит пеернаправление на /index.php/страница
Как-то можно добавить правило для https в эту строчку? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Поменять правила местами?

Comment: @de_frag пробовал, там ошибка, вообще не открывается